# Iterate through elements of multidimensional array and find neighbors - no numpy or imports

Tags: python, arrays, list, recursion, multidimensional-array

In python, how do I iterate through elements of a multidimensional array and find its neighbors without using numpy or any imports, just recursion? For example, `minesweeper_board = [[[0, 'b'], [0, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [0, 0], ['b', 0]], [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]]` with `'b'` marking a bomb, and I want to update the bomb count around each of the zeros (like in the minesweeper game).

Comment: So before I get into the answer, I'm having a hard time visualizing your data structure- could you provide a little more info on how it is structured?

Comment: For ```minesweeper_board```, ```dimensions = (4, 3, 2)``` -> 3d board - my question is asking for how to recursively iterate through the elements of an nth-dimensional array with a tuple of dimensions (length n) and find neighbors.

Comment: Why recursively?

Comment: @James I get that, I want to answer your question as confidently as possibly- The example that you provided doesn't quite fit your comment and I'm just trying to think about the best way to search this. You provided a list of 4 arrays, each array having 3, 2x1 tuples. I'm just having a hard time visualizing how this fits into 3d space.

Comment: @Błotosmętek, recursively because I want to be able to find neighbors of cells in an n-dimensional grid - if it was a set 3d grid, I would easily be able to find neighbors by getting the indices of cells at +/- 1 index on each dimension.@matt murray, a list with dimensions of (4,3,2) is 4 layers of 3x2 squares.

Comment: Ah, I see, you have **variable** number of dimensions. Now that makes for an interesting problem…

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest building a dictionary of links to neighbour coordinates for each row/column pair.  This can be used as an indirection in many parts of the program where you need to compute values around a position:

```
minesweeper_board = [ [ [0, 'b'], [0, 0], [0, 0]   ],
                      [ [0, 0],   [0, 0], ['b', 0] ],
                      [ [0, 0],   [0, 0], [0, 0]   ],
                      [ [0, 0],   [0, 0], [0, 0]   ]
                    ]

rows      = 4
cols      = 3
offsets   = [(-1,-1),(-1,0),(-1,1),(0,-1),(0,1),(1,-1),(1,0),(1,1)]

def inBoard(r,c): return r in range(rows) and c in range(cols)

def getNeighbours(r,c): return [(r+v,c+h) for v,h in offsets if inBoard(r+v,c+h)] 

links = { (r,c):getNeighbours(r,c) for r in range(rows) for c in range(cols) }
```

using the links dictionary:

```
for (r,c),neighbours in links.items():
    bombCount = sum('b' in minesweeper_board[nr][nc] for nr,nc in neighbours) 
    if bombCount:
        print(f"there are {bombCount} bombs near {(r,c)}")
```

output:

```
there are 2 bombs near (0, 1)
there are 1 bombs near (0, 2)
there are 1 bombs near (1, 0)
there are 2 bombs near (1, 1)
there are 1 bombs near (2, 1)
there are 1 bombs near (2, 2)
```

[EDIT] Generalization for multi-dimensional boards.

I initially misunderstood the question but the above solution can be generalized by creating recursive n-dimension access functions.  Python's list or lists structure doesn't lend itself well to indexing by multiple dimensions:  `board[1][2][3]` is a bit unwieldy compared to numpy's  `board[1,2,3]` but we can compensate for that using functions (or by creating a whole new class, which would be more work):

```
# access the value at a specific coordinate
def getCell(board,pos,*rest):
    return getCell(board[pos],*rest) if rest else board[pos]

# assign the value at a specific coordinate
def setCell(board,pos,*rest,value):
    if rest : setCell(board[pos],*rest,value=value)
    else:     board[pos] = value 

# get the values of the cell and all its neighbours at a coordinate 
def getNeighbours(board,pos,*rest):
    for nPos in (pos-1,pos,pos+1):
        if nPos not in range(len(board)): continue
        if not rest: yield board[nPos]; continue
        for value in getNeighbours(board[nPos],*rest):
            yield value

# iterate over the whole board returning coordinates and values    
def iterate(board):
    if not isinstance(board,list): yield ([],board); return
    for i,subBoard in enumerate(board):
        for coord,value in iterate(subBoard):
            yield ([i] + coord,value)

# assign counts of nearby bombs to each coordinate that is not a bomb
def countBombs(board):
    for coord,value in iterate(board):
        if value == "b": continue
        count = [*getNeighbours(board,*coord)].count("b")
        setCell(board,*coord,value=count)
```

output:

```
minesweeper_board = [ [ [0, 'b'], [0, 0], [0, 0]   ],
                      [ [0, 0],   [0, 0], ['b', 0] ],
                      [ [0, 0],   [0, 0], [0, 0]   ],
                      [ [0, 0],   [0, 0], [0, 0]   ]
                    ]

countBombs(minesweeper_board)
print(minesweeper_board)

[
   [ [1, 'b'], [2, 2], [1, 1]   ],
   [  [1, 1],  [2, 2], ['b', 1] ],
   [  [0, 0],  [1, 1], [1, 1]   ],
   [  [0, 0],  [0, 0], [0, 0]   ]
]


getCell(minesweeper_board,1,2,0) # 'b'
getCell(minesweeper_board,1,1,1) # 2
```

Comment: Great idea! However, I already have somewhat similar code for that - I just need code that can do this for a variable nth-dimensional list. I want to be able to construct a grid with any dimension tuple, say (4,3,2) for 3D, or even (5,3,6,2,8,5) for 6D (which I already have code for) and the function should get neighbors of each cell by recursively getting adjacent cells at each location.

Comment: I like this trick with unpacking `rest` into `pos` and `rest` in function call. I have doubts about `[*getNeighbours(board,*coord)]` though - is it better than `list(getNeighbours(board,*coord))` in any way?

Comment: No it's just shorter to write.  I originally had `sum(v=="b" for v in getNeighbours(board,*coord))` which is probably faster to execute.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem where I had to make alternative for numpy.exp() function as it can iterate through nth-dimensional list. But I couldn't find any solution on the web, and this was the only stackoverflow thread I could find, but didn't find the solution. So I made the function myself to go through an nth-dimensional list using recursion.
The iterate(list) function takes in an nth-dimensional list and iterates through it using recursion.

```
import math

def iterate(list1):
    for x in range(len(list1)):
        if isinstance(list1[x], list):
            iterate(list1[x])
        else:
            list1[x]=math.exp(list1[x]) # Manipulate the elements as you require

list2 = [[[2, 1], [3, 5], [6, 7]], [[8, 9], [6, 7], [12, 5]], [[3, 7], [2, 2], [3, 4]], [[5, 6], [7, 8], [9, 8]]]
iterate(list2)
print(list2)
```

This particular method will change each element x in an nth-dimensional list1 to e^x.

Output:

```
[[[7.38905609893065, 2.718281828459045], [20.085536923187668, 148.4131591025766], [403.4287934927351, 1096.6331584284585]], [[2980.9579870417283, 8103.083927575384], [403.4287934927351, 1096.6331584284585], [162754.79141900392, 148.4131591025766]], [[20.085536923187668, 1096.6331584284585], [7.38905609893065, 7.38905609893065], [20.085536923187668, 54.598150033144236]], [[148.4131591025766, 403.4287934927351], [1096.6331584284585, 2980.9579870417283], [8103.083927575384, 2980.9579870417283]]]
```